# algorithm to convert byte arrays to String supporting charsets in java

Tags: android, string, arrays

In java you can use the following code to convert a byte array to string.

```
new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

this method has problem with files more than 900 KB.

in my case I have a WebService sending a file

```
WebService: File-> Base64-> encrypted string
```

in android i want to get this file:

```
Android: encrypted string-> decrypted string -> Base64 -> file
```

I have problem in decryption in line new String(bytes, "UTF-8"); for files more than 900 MB.

I want to implement this method. Can anybody give me the source code of this method?

If you ignore the Charset, it is easy to convert a byte array to a string.

```
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    myString += (char) byteArray[i];
}
```

I am worry about the charset.
Can anybody help me?

---

**edit:**

I wrote the following code:

```
Charset charsetInput = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
CharsetDecoder decoder = charsetInput.newDecoder();
CharBuffer cbuf = decoder.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes));
String result = cbuf.toString();
```

But nothing changed.
At line 3 application stops unexpectedly.

Comment: Android + (Strings > 900 MB).... hmm..

Comment: I receive an encrypted file from webservice containing a binary file converted to Base64.

Comment: how can we load 900 MB byte array within the application, is that possible ??!!

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. 900KB. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29), you can use [`CharsetDecoder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html), specifically [this override](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html#decode%28java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20java.nio.CharBuffer,%20boolean%29) of `decode`.  You can get a source [`ByteBuffer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) by taking a [`FileInputStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html), calling [`getChannel`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html#getChannel%28%29), then calling [map](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map%28java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long%29) on that.  To avoid memory problems, you can output to a [`CharBuffer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/CharBuffer.html) similarly mapped to a file.

Comment: I am new in java. can you give me a sample or a link for using CharsetDecoder?
thanks,

Comment: @breceive, I suggest you make an attempt, and if you need help, post a follow-up question with your code.